# Linear Algebra, Spans and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V= \mathbb{R^3}$ and consider the following elements of $V$: $\mathbf{u}_1 =(1,2,0)$, $\mathbf{u}_2=(3,1,0)$, $\mathbf{u}_3=(1,-1,1)$. Let $U= \langle\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2\rangle$ and $W=\langle\mathbf{u}_3\rangle$.

$\mathbf{u}_3$ doesn't belong to $U$, I checked this by doing $\alpha \mathbf{u}_1+\beta \mathbf{u}_2= \mathbf{u}_3$. The next question asks: “is $U \cup W$ closed under multiplication by scalars and closed under addition? Therefore is  $U \cup W$ a subspace of $V$?”

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18140/discussion-on-question-by-dave-linear-algebra-spans-and-subspaces).

Comment: @theartist we don't know that U and W are subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. $U\cup W$ is always closed under multiplication by scalars, if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces
2. $U\cup W$ is a subspace if and only if $U\subseteq W$ or $W\subseteq U$ (check closure under addition)